'You and Me' versus 'You and I' - which is correct?
I’ve seen both versions being used by many people, but here’s what I follow. It might not be perfect, but I remember reading about the reasoning behind it. Happy to be corrected.
A. You and I: Use this when referring to ourselves in the first person (as opposed to “he/me” which is second person).

Correct Usage: You and I could not have completed the homework since we were late.

Incorrect Usage: You and Me could not have completed the homework since we were late.

Incorrect Usage: I and You could not have completed the homework since we were late.


B. Adam and I: Use this when referring to a person by name.

Correct Usage: Adam and I were the first to reach the beautiful lake in Kodaikanal.

Incorrect usage: I and Adam were the first to reach the beautiful lake in Kodaikanal.


C. The President and Me: Use this when referring to a position/title instead of a name. It should be followed by ‘Me’ when addressing in the second person.

Correct Usage: The President and Me discussed several initiatives that would help teenagers.

Incorrect Usage: The President and I discussed several initiatives that would help teenagers.


Remember this logic: The other person gets first preference, always e.g., “You and I,” “Aimee and I.” It’s not ideal to say, “I and You” or “I and Aimee.”

A and C are just wrong. We use You and I as the sentence subject, and You and me as object. In everyday AE conversation, we may answer "Who's going?" with "You and me" as acceptable against the rule, but that's casual. You and Me Against the World.

We give advice on informal English too, and you and me as a subject is common in informal speech even if many people consider it incorrect. Although informally "Me and the President" is more common than "The president and me". Still if you're studying English it's better to follow the rules.

1st part of A seems to be correct. When 'You and I' are the subjects (as mentioned by Yosef) and the ones performing the action, this is correct.  “You and I could not have completed the homework since we were late.” Here, “You and I” are the subjects who could not complete the homework .
However When “you and me” are receiving the action (object), you use “You and me.”
Example: “The teacher gave you and me extra homework.”
Here, “you and me” are the objects receiving the extra homework.

C is wrong. Thank you for correcting me. "The President and I' are subjects. All this while I was using it incorrectly.
As a new contributor, should I edit my question? or is it best to leave it since readers may benefit from your comments. Thank you Yosef.

The other person gets first preference? I think this is nonsense. It has to do with possible politeness, but gas nothing to do with grammar.
